# C++ read file only gives first word

Tags: c++, fstream

I know that I shouldn't use namespace std (`using namespace std`) as global in this scope, but for this example, I will.

What I ideally want, is to save text to a .txt file and retrieve it. I know that the **best** option would be `fstream` and so I decided to use it.

The below code prints out "This". Why does it print out "This" and not the full text?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;
    string text;

    fout.open("C++_text_file_test.txt");
    fout << "This is basic text";
    fout.close();

    fin.open("C++_text_file_test.txt");
    fin >> text;
    fin.close();

    cout << text << endl;
    cin.get(); // waits for user to press enter 

    return 0;
}
```

I tried researching but didn't quite understand the process of using a loop. Is there an easier way or can someone please explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `>>` operator, when used to extract a string, only grabs the characters up to the first white space character.  Try using `getline` to get the whole line.